# Can I use my dishwasher solely for drying?

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

I prefer washing dishes by hand but I want to dry them using the dishwasher. I use the Blomberg DW51600 SS dishwasher. This has an Express dry function. But when I select this function it still proceeds to perform the wash cycles before drying. I have checked its manual but no help.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to use it to only dry the dishes.

[image]

Comment: No there is no option you can select to only run a drying cycle.

Comment: It is a rare feature sometimes called "plate warmer".

Comment: Check into the sanitize option. Does that just heat the dishes or is it an added cycle after washing?

Comment: Sanitize just raises the water temperature (to 162 deg. F according to my Bosch manual)

Answer (score 5):

#### Absolutely!

1. Open the dishwasher.
2. Hand wash dishes.
3. Place wet, freshly washed items in the dishwasher racks.
4. Allow items to dry.

On a more serious note... Dishwashers are designed to *wash* dishes - it's right there in the name. There are some dishwashers that don't even have a "dry cycle", they're designed to wash, then allow the items to drip dry.

You might, with enough time, find a dishwasher that has a "dry only" cycle, but they're probably few and far between.

*That said, you may want to contact the manufacturer to see if there is a magical incantation of buttons you can push to get a "dry only" run, but I'd doubt it.*

Answer (score -1):

The one at our apartment is an inexpensive dishwasher and does have that option to only dry dishes and I love it, because the one I have in my house in Mexico also does the whole washing cycle before it dryers the dishes and I also prefer to wash some dishes by hand, but don’t like to dry them by hand or on the counter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Simply sharing the brand/model number of the dishwasher ([edit] them into your answer) would go a long way to improving your answer. As it stands, it's kinda like me saying, "hey, I just bought a brand new car for $1000 that gets 100 MPG" and walking away. Leaves you wanting more, doesn't it?